# UITableView and UICollectionView in ViewController, didn't works in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I have implemented a calendar in a Collection. Below the collection there is a Tableview with activities of the day selected in the calendar. I do a reload when I select a day and works perfect in iOS7, BUT in iOS8 the TableView doesn't pass by `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

**iPhone 4s - iOS7**

[image: iPhone 4s screen on iOS7]

**iPhone 4s - iOS8**

[image: iPhone 4s on iOS8 - broken]

All the delegates (for table and collection) are declared.

Comment: Try checking if the table view's size is zero. Zero sized table views don't bother creating the cells.

Comment: @EranGoldin in iOS8 doen't pass  by (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: @FlavioFranco share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug, I was using a constraint **height equals or less** in my tableView and later I modified programmatically the constraint depending the size screen. That works fine in iOS7 but no in iOS 8 :C

Just I changed the constraint height of the tableview to **equals** and works good :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWlwn.png

Answer (score 0):

**1**: *Verify your gesture in this controller*

Are you implement an UITapGesture or UISwipeGesture in this controller ?
The gesture object get the focus on table view gesture.

**2**: *Verify your architecture amd64*

If you use amd64 architecture, verify you use CGFloat and not float in your delegate method.
In architecture amd64, CGFloat is a double and not a float. UI can be not response properly.

K.